# Laravel 4 rest controller 404 error

Tags: routes, laravel-4

How can I call App::abort(404) on action, that does not exist?

When I go to url /logindfghdfghdfghhdfgh(some non-real url), I want to show 404 page, but it show me first action in controller.

please, help

```
Route::get('/login', 'UserController@getLogin');
Route::post('/login', 'UserController@postLogin');

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::controller('/codes', 'CodeController');
});

Route::controller('/users', 'UserController');

Route::controller('/', 'PromoController');
```

Comment: Please show us your routes.

Comment: Did you add an `App::missing()` like described at http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-404-errors

Comment: yes, I add App::missing, but it's not work

Answer (score 0):

As JackPoint mentions in comments, if you add

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

somewhere that is going to be pulled in on boot up, eg. in app/start/global.php would work, then it should show a custom error page on 404 - in the above example you would need to have an errors folder under your views folder and in there a missing.blade.php view file (if you are using blade views that is).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!Request::is('/')){
        App::abort(404);
    }
```

I add this in my get() method, and it's work with App::missing().